# Java2D OpenGL graphics acceleration not working

Tags: java, swing, opengl, look-and-feel

I want to use Swing together with the Java2D OpenGL graphics acceleration. However, it does not work.

I answered this by myself, since I searched for the solution for quite some time.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class OpenGLTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        // set system look and feel
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        // activate opengl
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");

        // create and show the GUI in the event dispatch thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("OpenGL Test");
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem

The problem with the above code is, that it interacts with a Swing class before the property `"sun.java2d.opengl"` is set to `"true"`. Setting the look and feel already counts as such an interaction.

### Verifying the Problem

You can see this by setting the property `"sun.java2d.opengl"` to `"True"` instead of `"true"`. As described in the [Java2D Properties Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html), this causes Java to output the following message to the console when it activates OpenGL graphics acceleration:

```
OpenGL pipeline enabled for default config on screen 0
```

Executing the code from the question with the property set to `"True"` does not output this message. This indicates that the OpenGL graphics acceleration is not activate.

### Solution

To solve this, set the property before setting the look and feel.

Replace this

```
        // set system look and feel
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        // activate opengl
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
```

by this

```
        // activate opengl
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True");

        // set system look and feel
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

This causes the code to display the debugging message given above, which indicates that OpenGL graphics acceleration is indeed activated.

Comment: Wouldn't you normal pass the property via the commandline with `-D`?

Comment: The `-D` parameter is essentially the same as the method `setProperty`. However, it is not always possible to use the parameter. For example, if you deliver an executable jar file without an installer and without the additional starter script for each operating system.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just thinking it's easier to toggle it on and off (and I normally have my programs wrapped in a .exe or .app package)

Comment: It is certainly another working solution to the same problem. I guess each solution covers a slightly different use case. Also, you miss the Linux users by just providing the .exe and .app files.